# NameError at /test_submit/ name 'item_name' is not defined in Django

Tags: django, nameerror

Hello Iam new in django and i try to same my form input to database without form.py just from views but iam getting name error please help me to short out the problem

**This is my html form code**

```
<form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-black w3-margin" method="post" action="/test_submit/" id='myForm'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="w3-row-padding">
      <div class="w3-half">
         <p><label>Item Name</label></p>
         <p><input class="w3-input" type="text" name="item_name" required></p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-half">
         <p><label>Brand Name</label></p>
         <p><input class="w3-input" type="text" name="brand_name" required></p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="w3-row-padding">
     <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>Item Size</label></p>
      <p><select class="w3-select" name="item_size" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Size</option>
      <option value="5k-7k">5k-7k</option>
      <option value="7k-10k">7k-10k</option>
      <option value="11-13">11-13</option>
      <option value="1-3">1-3</option>
      <option value="4-5">4-5</option>
      <option value="6-9">6-9</option>
      <option value="10-11">10-11</option>
      </select></p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-half">
    <p><label>Item Color</label></p>
     <p><input class="w3-input" type="text" name="item_color" required></p>
   </div>

    <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>Item Unit</label></p>
     <p><select class="w3-select" name="item_unit" required>
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Unit</option>
     <option value="Number">Number</option>
     <option value="Number">Number</option>
     <option value="Boxes">Boxes</option>
     </select></p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>Quantity</label></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input" type="number" name="item_quantity" placeholder="0" required></p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>Purchase Price</label></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input" type="number" name="purchase_price" placeholder="0.0" required></p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>Selling Price</label></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input" type="number" name="selling_price" placeholder="0.0" required></p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>MRP</label></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input" type="number" name="mrp" placeholder="0.0" required></p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-half">
      <p><label>Date</label></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input" type="date" name="date" required></p>
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="w3-bar">
      <button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-round">Save</button>
      <button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-round">Save & Generate Barcode</button>
      <button class="w3-btn w3-gray w3-round" onclick="clearFun()">Cancle</button>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</form>
```

**This is my views.py code**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Items_Tb
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def items_views(request):
    return render(request,'itemapp/items.html')

def items_submit_views(request):
    print('----------------test my submit form-----------------')
    itemname = request.POST[item_name]
    brandname = request.POST[brand_name]
    itemsize = request.POST[item_size]
    itemcolor = request.POST[item_color]
    itemunit = request.POST[item_unit]
    itemquantity = request.POST[item_quantity]
    purchaseprice = request.POST[purchase_price]
    sellingprice = request.POST[selling_price]
    mrp = request.POST[mrp]
    item_date = request.POST[date]

    item_info = Items_Tb(item_name=itemname,brand_name=brandname,item_size=itemsize,
    item_color=itemcolor,item_unit=itemunit,item_quantity=itemquantity,purchase_price=purchaseprice,
    selling_price=sellingprice,mrp=mrp,item_date=item_date)

    item_info.save()
    messages.success(request,'Items save successfully!')

    return render(request,'itemapp/items.html')
```

This is models.py Code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Items_Tb(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    item_size =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
    item_color = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    item_unit =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    purchase_price = models.FloatField()
    selling_price =  models.FloatField()
    mrp = models.FloatField()
    item_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):#show tabel name on admin
        return self.item_name
```

**This is my Urls.py Code**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from dashboardapp import views as d_views
from itemapp import views as i_views
from userapp import views as u_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dashboard/', d_views.dash_views),
    path('test/', d_views.test_views),
    path('items/', i_views.items_views, name='items'),
    path('test_submit/', i_views.items_submit_views, name='test_submit'),
    path('users/', u_views.users_views),
]
```

when i sumbit my form iam getting this error
bellow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFlYF.png)

Answer (score 0):

`item_name` should be in quotes:

```
itemname = request.POST["item_name"]
```

Comment: Yeah, this answer is right, all your POST dictionary keys are wrong. In your case Python tries to find variable `item_name` in local variables and doesn't found it.

Also, you don't use any kind of validation, Django Forms could be suitable for both cases https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/